# MS Access 2007/2010: Need to set Date field based on most recent of 5 other Date fields

Tags: ms-access, expression

I seem to have a problem I haven't encountered before within the same record.  I need to set a Date field value based on the most recent date of 5 other Date fields.  I would like to do this at the query level so that I can assign the most recent date and store it in a field, but I'm not sure if it's possible.  If I have to do it within a Form, then I'm not sure how to write out the Case statement.  Any help is appreciated!

What I'm trying to do now is write an expression that pretty much goes as follows:

```
ESA Exp Date: IIf([1-Record Search Date]>[2-Site Reconnaissance Date] And [1-Record Search Date]>[3-Owner Interview Date] And [1-Record Search Date]>[4-Lien/AUL Search Date] And [1-Record Search Date]>[5-User Questionnaire Date],[1-Record Search Date],IIf([2-Site Reconnaissance Date]>[1-Record Search Date]
```

And so on...  However, expressions have a limit of characters, and so someone said in an unrelated question to write a function.  I'm not sure how that would work in my case though.

Thanks again
Rob

Answer (score 2):

The reason this seems so difficult is because your table structure is not optimal for relational querying. Let's say your current table (`date_values`) has the columns `d1` to `d5`, all dates. You need to *normalise* the table like so (note that this doesn't change your actual table, it just 'repackages' it in memory into an easier-to-query form):

```
select entity_id, 'type 1' as date_type, d1 as date_value
from date_values
where d1 is not null
union all
select entity_id, 'type 2' as date_type, d2 as date_value
from date_values
where d2 is not null
union all
select entity_id, 'type 3' as date_type, d3 as date_value
from date_values
where d3 is not null
union all
select entity_id, 'type 4' as date_type, d4 as date_value
from date_values
where d4 is not null
union all
select entity_id, 'type 5' as date_type, d5 as date_value
from date_values
where d5 is not null
```

Note that `entity_id` is any field which uniquely identifies a row in your table. Once you have data in a normalised form, querying is easy:*

```
update date_values as d
inner join (
  select ssq.entity_id, max(ssq.date_value) as max_date
  from (
    ... the query I show above ...
  ) as ssq
  group by ssq.entity_id
) as sq
on d.entity_id = sq.entity_id
set d.[ESA Exp Date] = sq.max_date
where entity_id = [... the entity you wish to update ...]
```

The last clause above, the `where` clause, restricts the modification to a single row you can specify. You can enter it manually when prompted by Access or you can have it refer to a field in a form. There are many options.

`*` OK, easi_er_.

Comment: Thanks for your input (both). For this one, I'm not sure yet if you're referring to evaluating all records or just the one I'm working on.  I will look into this though. = )

Comment: @RARascon - the above query will update all records in one step, but if you want to limit it you can add on a `where` clause at the end to choose only a single row (or more). I'll edit my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: +1 having read through your answer properly (I didn't take enough time to think it through the first time) it's a great solution. The function is easier to use for a beginner (IMO) but this is a better purist solution and probably performs better on larger datasets. I'll need to find somewhere I can implement something like this now...

Comment: @Simon1979 - thanks, I'd expect it to do pretty well on larger datasets with some careful indexing. With Access though, you might need to go to some extreme lengths (like creating and indexing lookup tables) to index properly.

Answer (score 2):

If changing your table structure isn't an option then you can use a function like the one created by Allen Browne http://allenbrowne.com/func-09.html, there are fuller instructions on the webpage.

Call it in a query as:  (may I suggest not putting spaces in whenever not required, will help further down the line in VBA)

```
ESAExpDate: MaxOfList([1-Record Search Date],_
[2-Site Reconnaissance Date],[3-Owner Interview Date],[4-Lien/AUL Search Date], _
[5-User Questionnaire Date])
```

I have pasted below in case the link dies.

```
Function MaxOfList(ParamArray varValues()) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer        'Loop controller.
    Dim varMax As Variant   'Largest value found so far.

    varMax = Null           'Initialize to null

    For i = LBound(varValues) To UBound(varValues)
        If IsNumeric(varValues(i)) Or IsDate(varValues(i)) Then
            If varMax >= varValues(i) Then
                'do nothing
            Else
                varMax = varValues(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    MaxOfList = varMax
End Function
```

Comment: I think this may be more along the lines of what I'm dealing with, but don't know until I implement it.  Many thanks!  And so what do you mean not willing to change my table structure?  Would I be able to accomplish this within the table rather than a query?

Comment: Also, I believe it addresses an issue that I forgot to mention with null values.  So, the 5 date fields may include nulls on some or all of the fields.  It seems this function will manage that, but let me know if I should be aware of something along those lines. Thx again!

Comment: @RARascon, My initial comment was regarding Yawar's suggestion of changing you table structure; yes to optimise relational querying changing your table structure could allow you to query this more easily, however if your database is established (and difficult to change table structure) or having the table structure with fields for each date is required for another reason then the above will work.

Comment: @RARascon, No I don't think there is anything else you need to be concerned about, the function handles `Null`, only returning `Null` if none of the passed values are numeric/ date.

Comment: I see - thank you for clarifying that! I will be testing this later tonight.

Comment: @RARascon - I've updated my answer to clarify that the query doesn't restructure your database on disk--just in memory while it is running. Also, it definitely handles `null`s because I explicitly filter them out.

Comment: OMG it's working!  I'm still testing, but it has worked with the data I have so far, which is only a handful of records.  Like I said, I've used Access for many years, and have never come across a scenario like this.  Very good to know there was an easy, relevant solution, but would not have found it had it not been suggested from sites such as this one. Thanks again!

Comment: I've tested new records - working beautifully!  I wish I could vote 10 on this one!